# JQuery not working angularjs controller file . Works if code snippet put internally

Tags: jquery, angularjs, single-page-application

below code snippet works fine if placed under Template URL page . However, if we put it in spearate js file or  controler file it doesnt work. How can i add jquery inside a controller file .

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#notificationLink").click(function () {
        $("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);
        $("#notification_count").fadeOut("slow");
        $('#notificationLink > i.fa-bell').addClass('fa-bell-o');
        $('#notificationLink > i.fa-bell').removeClass('fa-bell');
        return false;
    });

    //Document Click hiding the popup 
    $(document).click(function () {
        $("#notificationContainer").hide();
    });

    //Popup on click
    $("#notificationContainer").click(function () {
        return false;
    });

  /*  $('#AddNew').on('click', function () {
        $('#notificationsBody ul').append('<li>New Message</li>');
    });
*/
});
</srcipt>
```

Comment: Why don't you use only angular for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct place to use jQuery in an Angular app is in a directive with jqlite. You could also stick it in the same file of the controller, as long as it's after it.

Comment: Yes... I have read that !! .. and jquery works when put inside the custom directive.

Comment: .directive('notify',function(){
      return {
            scope: {},
            restrict: 'E',
            /*template : 'i am x',*/
            link : function(scope,element,attrs){
              $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#notificationLink').click(function () {
          $('#notificationContainer').fadeToggle(300);
          $('#notification_count').fadeOut('slow');
          $('#notificationLink > i.fa-bell').addClass('fa-bell-o');
          $('#notificationLink > i.fa-bell').removeClass('fa-bell');
          return false;
      });